# Getting the number of features in shapefile without opening it using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, features, count

I have some big shapefiles that takes dozens of minutes if not hours to load. I was wondering if there would be a way to get the size of the files (number of rows) without loading them entirely. I mostly work with Python (GeoPandas).

Exemple code of what I am currently using:

```
%%time
name = "exemple.shp"
df = geopandas.read_file(name)
len(df)
```

Outputting:

CPU times: user 35.5 s, sys: 2.06 s, total: 37.6 s
Wall time: 37.6 s
621812

The code is relatively long to run because it reads the whole file before calculating its length.

Comment: Try converting them to geopackages, the loading time will probably get better

Comment: The `.shx` file contains a static header and fixed records, so the record count is `(length_of_shx - 100) / 8`

Comment: However, shapefile may contain records which are marked as deleted by a flag in the .dbf file but they are still included in the .shp and .shx parts. This situation is usually temporary and deleted features are removed totally when the shapefile is repacked  and therefore the .shx way is probably the fastest method for getting a very good estimate.

Comment: The Question *feels* like something is missing. Shapefiles *can't* be large enough to take "hours" to load unless you're using a SATCOM link with a 1k blocking factor to a USB 1.0 2x CD-ROM. Yes, reading all the features is inefficient, but it's also the only reliable means of getting the *correct* answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way using `fiona`, which `geopandas` also uses behind the scenes:

```py
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd


with fiona.open("shapefile.shp") as features:
    print(len(features))

    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(features)
    print(gdf.head())
```

Comment: I chose to accept this answer as the most straightforward way without any additional dependency.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is not possible to get the feature count without *opening* at least some part of the shapefile but for sure it is not necessary to read all data.

With GDAL and Python

```
from osgeo import ogr

shp=ogr.Open("my_shapefile.shp")
shp_layer=shp.GetLayer(0)
shp_layer.GetFeatureCount()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you only need the number of features, use the standard Python module  [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) (used by [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp)). You only need to read the first bytes of the dbf or the .shp files (Raw Binary Files):

a) .dbf file : the first 32 bytes contain the header, which holds the number of records, the length of the header and the record length for each entry see [dbf file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf#File_header))

```
import struct
f = open("nodes.dbf",'rb')
header = f.read(32)
nrecs,hlen,rlen = struct.unpack('<4xihh20x',header) # format string
# number of records
print(nrecs)
100
```

b) .shp file: the first 100 bytes contain the header which holds the file length, the shape type and the coordinates of the bounding box, see [Shapefile shape format (.shp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_(.shp))

```
f = open("nodes.shp",'rb')
header = f.read(100)
# file length
shplen = struct.unpack('>l',header[24:28]) 
flength = shplen[0]*2 - 100 # file length in bytes
# shape type 
shptype = struct.unpack('<l',header[32:36]) # shape type
print(shptype[0])
1 # Points  
# bounding box
shpb = struct.unpack('<dddd',header[36:68])
print(shpb)
(112.5695435011522, 514.1993431885919, 187.88374236783451, 599.8600675239098)
# number of records: for each record, there are 28 bytes 
nrecs = flength / 28
print(nrecs)
100.0
```

Control with the  user30184 solution

```
from osgeo import ogr
shp=ogr.Open("nodes.shp")
shp_layer=shp.GetLayer(0)
shp_layer.GetFeatureCount()
100
```

Comment: You can only extract feature count from file length and feature type from `.shp` for `Point` type shapefiles (and the '28' would be different for PointZ, PointM, and PointZM variants). Any other type would require a full file scan. Extracting the length of the `.shx` is the only non-scanning solution (albeit vulnerable to "unclean" file contents).

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's possible, for example using [`ogrinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html) at the command line.

##### From your command line shell

Here in bash:

```sh
ogrinfo -ro -al -so my_shapefile.shp | grep -i "Feature Count"
Feature Count: 80416
```

Or simply `ogrinfo -ro -al -so my_shapefile.shp` to see the full metadata of your Shapefile.

##### From Python itself

You can also start a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) from Python to run the same command, e.g. with the first example:

```py
import sys
print(sys.version) # 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]


import subprocess

shpfile = '/path/to/my_shapefile.shp'

cmd = f'ogrinfo -ro -al -so {shpfile} | grep -i "Feature Count"'

res = subprocess.run(
    cmd,
    shell=True,
    capture_output=True,
    check=True,
    text=True,
    executable='/bin/bash',
)

print(res.stdout) # Feature Count: 80416

nbFeatures = int(res.stdout.split()[-1])

print(nbFeatures) # 80416

print(type(nbFeatures)) # <class 'int'>
```

More on the subprocess module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/6630397
Doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the [`PyShp`](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) library

```
# imports
from os.path import normpath
from shapefile import Reader

absolute_path_to_shp = normpath("C:/Users/taras/files/cluster_test.shp")
shp = Reader(absolute_path_to_shp)
print(shp.numRecords) # returns features count: 1208
```